# Nifi: Reading external properties in custom Processor

Tags: apache-nifi

I have updated the variable registry to point to a custom properties file and i am able to read those in my processors using expression language with out any issues.

How ever i want to read them in my Custom Processor's (extending the AbstractProcessor) onTrigger()

I tried flowFile.getAttributes() and context.getAllProperties() and it is not getting picked up.

Appreciate any inputs.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clarify, you want to reference the value of these externally-defined variables inside the application logic of your `CustomProcessor#onTrigger()` method?

You can:

1. Load the variable definitions by querying [`NiFiProperties#getVariableRegistryProperties()`](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-commons/nifi-properties/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/util/NiFiProperties.java#L1195) or [`NiFiProperties#getVariableRegistryPropertiesPaths`](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-commons/nifi-properties/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/util/NiFiProperties.java#L1199). Once you have a reference to the variable definitions, you can parse and use them as you wish.
2. You can reference them via the flowfile attributes or processor properties *if* those attributes or properties support Expression Language and it is appropriately scoped. The `PropertyDescriptor` will list `expressionLanguageSupported()` and return an `ExpressionLanguageScope`, which is an `enum` consisting of `NONE`, `VARIABLE_REGISTRY`, and `FLOWFILE_ATTRIBUTES` (which also includes the VR).

I don't understand the scenario where you want your code to load custom variables that aren't controllable by the flow administrator, which would be populated via processor properties or flowfile attributes. If you really feel you need to access custom variables that aren't available via the context or flowfile, you can use Option 1 above, but you could also theoretically store those variables in environment variables, System properties, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs Andy. In the mean time i have loaded the nifi.properties and the corresponding resources that are set for variable registry property and it is working as expected. With option 1 it looks like i need to extend that class and implement lot of abstract methods. Will take a closer look at that and see how i can refactor my changes. Thanks again

Comment: You absolutely do not need to extend `NiFiProperties`. You get an instance of that class and call the existing accessors. You really shouldn’t need to do anything with the class directly and I think you are misusing the VR. Those values should be read using EL in flowfile attributes or property processors in general.